# Flutter Calculate the Value in Field on different Document Firebase Firestore

Tags: list, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm kinda new in Flutter and struggle with the syntax in using Firestore.

[firebase][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQN8.jpg

[my code execution][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWOqM.jpg

```
Future getTotal() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(sharedPreferences!.getString("uid"))
        .collection("userCart").get();

    dynamic docs = querySnapshot.docs;
    var mapData = docs.map((res) => res['itemID.totalAmount']);

    List<String> totalAmount = mapData.toList().cast<String>();
    _userCartList = totalAmount;
    await sharedPreferences!.setStringList("totalAmount", totalAmount);

    print("Test: " + totalAmount.toString());
  }
```

Comment: could you plz add the code you have done so that it will be easier to tell the solution as we would know what method you are using to get the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here, I provided my codes